# Install usblib package - Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, usb, package-management, dpkg

I need the package libusb for another package I am installing.

I tried the following which seemed to install the package,

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
```

but when I try to install the other package I get,

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libusb-1.0 >= 0.9.1) were not met:

No package 'libusb-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBUSB_CFLAGS
and LIBUSB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

When I run the command dpkg -L libusb-dev, I get:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/libusb-config
/usr/include
/usr/include/usb.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libusb.a
/usr/lib/libusb.la
/usr/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libusb.pc
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/index.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/preface.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/intro.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/intro-overview.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/intro-support.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-device-interfaces.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-timeouts.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-types.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-synchronous.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-return-values.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/functions.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.core.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbinit.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbfindbusses.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbfinddevices.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetbusses.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.deviceops.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbopen.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbclose.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbsetconfiguration.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbsetaltinterface.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbresetep.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbclearhalt.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbreset.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbclaiminterface.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbreleaseinterface.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.control.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbcontrolmsg.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetstring.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetstringsimple.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetdescriptor.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetdescriptorbyendpoint.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.bulk.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbbulkwrite.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbbulkread.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.interrupt.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbinterruptwrite.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbinterruptread.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.nonportable.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetdrivernp.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbdetachkerneldrivernp.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples-code.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples-tests.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples-other.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc-base
/usr/share/doc-base/libusb-dev
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/libusb-config.1.gz
/usr/lib/libusb.so
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to install `libusb-1.0-0-dev`

To install the package

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

To find out the dependency of the package use the command `apt-cache search libusb-1.0`

Here is the output of the command

```
$ apt-cache search libusb-1.0
libusb-1.0-0 - userspace USB programming library
libusb-1.0-0-dev - userspace USB programming library development files
libusb-ocaml - OCaml bindings to libusb-1.0 (runtime)
libusb-ocaml-dev - OCaml bindings to libusb-1.0
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the package `libusb-1.0-0-dev`, the new [libusbx](http://libusbx.org/) fork.